# How an app in docker container access DB in windows?

Tags: docker, go

OS: Windows server 2016

I have an App wrote in Go and put in a docker container. The App has to access "D:\test.db". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and by using the `-v` or `--mount` flag when you start your container.

A modified example from the Docker docs:

```
$ docker run -d \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

you just need to replace `nginx:latext` with your image name and adapt `source` and `target` as you need.

Another example (also from the docs) using `-v` and mounting in read-only mode:

```
$ docker run -d \
  -v nginx-vol:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
  nginx:latest
```